# Writing DAO : how to override or implements the interface methods in abstract class?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working with Spring 3.2 and Hibernate 4. I am writing the persistence layer access with dao. Here is the dao interface code :

```
public interface AbstractDao<E, I extends Serializable> {

    public E findById(I id);
    public void saveOrUpdate(E e);
    public void delete(E e);
    public List<E> findByCriteria(Criterion criterion);
}
```

Just after I have written following the abstract class which implements the interface :

```
public abstract class AbstractDaoImpl<E, I extends Serializable> implements AbstractDao<E,I> {

        private Class<E> entityClass;

        protected AbstractDaoImpl(Class<E> entityClass) {
            this.entityClass = entityClass;
        }

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public Session getCurrentSession() {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }

        @Override
        public E findById(I id) {
            return (E) getCurrentSession().get(entityClass, id);
        }

        @Override
        public void saveOrUpdate(E e) {
            getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void delete(E e) {
            getCurrentSession().delete(e);
        }

        @Override
        public List<E> findByCriteria(Criterion criterion) {
            Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entityClass);
            criteria.add(criterion);
            return criteria.list();
        }
}
```

I am getting some compilation errors on all methods that i have implemented in the abstract class : `findById(I id)`, `saveOrUpdate(E e)`, `delete(E e)` ,`findByCriteria(Criterion criterion)`.

The error message is :

> Multiple markers at this line
>   
>    - implements com.startup.app.models.hibernate.dao.AbstractDao.findById
>   
>    - The method findById(I) of type AbstractDaoImpl must override a superclass 
>        method

What wrong, I don't understand. thanks.
[image]

Comment: It compiles fine for me.

Comment: Did you remove override annotation ?

Comment: I copy-pasted your code exactly.

Comment: This code works fine for me.Just try clean building it once

Comment: You're probably using Java 5 to compile this code, where @Override couldn't be used to indicate an interface method implementation. Use Java 7 or at least 6. Java 5 is completely obsolete.

Comment: FWIW, save yourself the hassle and look into Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are using atleast **Java 1.6** inorder to use `@Override` in this case.

In Java 1.5, `@Override` could only be applied to methods overriding a superclass method.